# Is there anyway to generate integer numbers with Latin Hypercube Sampling method in R?

Tags: r, random, sampling

I would like to generate a few **random interger numbers**. But `LHS` only returns continuous numbers.

Note: I know that if I use functions like `floor`, they violate the underlying assumptions of the method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a R package called `lhs`, which has this function named `runifint()`, which has this capability. See the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lhs/lhs.pdf) at page 34. Unfortunately, it's not included in my local R installation, for which I filed a issue in github [bertcarnell/lhs](https://github.com/bertcarnell/lhs/issues).